# How can I rewrite this fixture call so it won't be called directly?

Tags: python, pytest, decorator, fixtures

I defined the following fixture in a test file:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from packaging import version # for comparing version numbers

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
VERSION = os.environ.get("VERSION")
API_URL = os.environ.get("API_URL")

@pytest.fixture()
def skip_before_version():
    """
    Creates a fixture that takes parameters
    skips a test if it depends on certain features implemented in a certain version

    :parameter target_version:
    :parameter type: string
    """
    def _skip_before(target_version):
        less_than = version.parse(current_version) < version.parse(VERSION) 
        return pytest.mark.skipif(less_than)
    return _skip_before


skip_before = skip_before_version()("0.0.1")
```

I want to use `skip_before` as a fixture in certain tests.  I call it like this:

```
#@skip_before_version("0.0.1")     # tried this before and got the same error, so tried reworking it...
@when(parsers.cfparse("{categories} are added as categories"))
def add_categories(skip_before, create_tree, categories):   # now putting the fixture alongside parameters
    pass
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Fixture "skip_before_version" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.
```

How is this still being called directly?  How can I fix this?

Comment: _How is this still being called directly?_ - because of the `skip_before = skip_before_version("0.0.1")` line. _How can I fix this?_ - it's not quite clear from the code what you are trying to achieve, and the code looks broken. E.g. `skip_before_version` doesn't expect any arguments, yet you are passing "0.0.1" to it.

Comment: @hoefling   You're right, I should call `skip_before_version` before passing aruments to the function it returns, i.e. `skip_before = skip_before_version()("0.0.1")`.

Comment: @hoefling  I'm still not sure how to use this fixture, which will skip the test if the version isn't high enough (meaning it needs to take a version number as an argument).  I can't add this fixture as a parameter to a function, since it's invalid syntax, nor can I call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to be able to skip tests based on a version restriction specifier. There are many ways to do that; I can suggest an autouse fixture that will skip the test based on a custom marker condition. Example:

```
import os
import pytest
from packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet


VERSION = "1.2.3"  # read from environment etc.


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_based_on_version_compat(request):
    # get the version_compat marker
    version_compat = request.node.get_closest_marker("version_compat")
    if version_compat is None:  # test is not marked
        return

    if not version_compat.args:  # no specifier passed to marker
        return

    spec_arg = version_compat.args[0]
    spec = SpecifierSet(spec_arg)

    if VERSION not in spec:
        pytest.skip(f"Current version {VERSION} doesn't match test specifiers {spec_arg!r}.")
```

The fixture `skip_based_on_version_compat` will be invoked on each test, but only do something if the test is marked with `@pytest.mark.version_compat`. Example tests:

```
@pytest.mark.version_compat(">=1.0.0")
def test_current_gen():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.version_compat(">=2.0.0")
def test_next_gen():
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

With `VERSION = "1.2.3"`, the first test will be executed, the second one will be skipped. Notice the invocation of [`pytest.skip`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-skip) to immediately skip the test. Returning `pytest.mark.skip` in the fixture will bring you nothing since the markers are already evaluated long before that.

Also, I noticed you are writing gherkin tests (using `pytest-bdd` presumably). With the above approach, skipping the whole scenarios should be also possible:

```
@pytest.mark.version_compat(">=1.0.0")
@scenario("my.feature", "my scenario")
def test_scenario():
    pass
```

Alternatively, you can mark the scenarios in feature files:

```
Feature: Foo
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

    @version_compat(">=1.0.0")
    Scenario: doing future stuff
        Given foo is implemented
        When I see foo
        Then I do bar
```

and use [`pytest-bdd`-own hooks](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=skip#organizing-your-scenarios):

```
def pytest_bdd_apply_tag(tag, function):
    matcher = re.match(r'^version_compat\("(?P<spec_arg>.*)"\)$', tag)
    spec_arg = matcher.groupdict()["spec_arg"]
    spec = SpecifierSet(spec_arg)
    if VERSION not in spec:
        marker = pytest.mark.skip(
            reason=f"Current version {VERSION} doesn't match restriction {spec_arg!r}."
        )
        marker(function)
        return True
```

Unfortunately, neither custom fixtures nor markers will work with skipping in single steps (and you will still be skipping the whole scenario since it is an atomic test unit in gherkin). I didn't find a reliable way to befriend `pytest-bdd` steps with pytest stuff; looks like they are simply ignored. Nevertheless, you can easily write a custom decorator serving the same purpose:

```
import functools


def version_compat(spec_arg):

    def deco(func):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            spec = SpecifierSet(spec_arg)
            if VERSION not in spec:
                pytest.skip(f"Current version {VERSION} doesn't match test specifiers {spec_arg!r}.")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return deco
```

Using `version_compat` deco in a step:

```
@when('I am foo')
@version_compat(">=2.0.0")
def i_am_foo():
    ...
```

Pay attention to the ordering - placing decorators outside of `pytest-bdd`'s own stuff will not trigger them (I guess worth opening an issue, but meh).